# Intercept response in XML with chosen file (in .xml format, too) and parse it into Cypress

Tags: xml, cypress, assert

since that I am new in Cypress, hope that anyone can help.
Namely, have .xml response body saved in file inside cypress folder (actually at, /fixtures/file.xml). What I am trying to achieve to somehow parse xml into JS object, in order to write test which will check several articles (and each of it has: thumbnail, title, impress text - usual elements).
What acchieved so far - found that file, printed it on console.log

```
cy.route('**{part_of_URL_response**', 'fixture:file.xml').as(
  'articlePosts',
 );
});

it('should contain list of articles', () => {
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/file.xml').then(articlePosts  
=> {
   cy.get(articlePosts).should('exist');
  });
```

But, assertion line is not working properly, not understand why.
Is that assertion correct - just want to confirm element existence?
Is there any solution to convert/parse file.xml into JS object(s) and iterate later, to assert elements on page?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for this:
Just add into mock request all necessary data, not just cy.server command:

```
cy.server({
  method: '{Request: - GET or POST}',
  url: '{PartURL_on_which_sending_request}',
  status: {response_status_code},
});
cy.route('{PartURL_on_which_sending_request}', 'fixture:file.xml').as(
  '{aliasName}',
);
```

Assertion were correct, issue was on mocking data